# Rows to columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, row

I'm developping a tool which generates an excel table with SQL results.
I have several days, several payment methods (fe: credit card, check, species) and several sums.
I am doing this request :

```
SELECT TE.DATE AS 'JOUR', SUM(TE.TOTAL_TTC) AS 'CA TTC', ME.LIBELLE AS 'LIBELLE'
FROM TICKET TE
INNER JOIN MODE_REGLEMENT ME ON ME.CODE = TE.MODE_REGLEMENT
GROUP BY TE.DATE, ME.LIBELLE
```

(MODE_REGLEMENT means payment method)

And i have this result :

```
**JOUR**           **CA TTC**      **LIBELLE**
07/03/2014         1409.66         CREDIT CARD
07/03/2014         70              CHECK
07/03/2014         1393.31         SPECIES
08/03/2014         3368.07         CREDIT CARD
08/03/2014         599.44          SPECIES
09/03/2014         268.7           CREDIT CARD
09/03/2014         174.62          CHECK
```

But i'm searching to generate something like that :

```
**JOUR**     **CA TTC**     **CREDIT CARD**     **CHECK**     **SPECIES**
07/03/2014   2872.97        1409.66             70            1393.31
08/03/2014   3967.51        3368.07             0             599.44
09/03/2014   443.32         268.7               174.62        0
```

The column 'CA TTC' will be the sum of each payment methods.
Can you please help me to do a request (for SQL Server) to have the result i want.

Thank you a lot !
(sorry for the bad english i'm french)

Comment: Use PIVOT. To Know about PIVOT Check LINK http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/06/07/sql-server-pivot-and-unpivot-table-examples/

Comment: Please, read this article I wrote: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/796651/Client-Side-Multi-Column-Dynamic-Pivot

Comment: @ConsiderItDone i'm using your solution but i have a name of a column separate by a blank ( CPTE CLIENT ), how can i set it ?

Comment: @BlackAlpha --- U have to alias it to some other name. In your case if its (CPTE CLIENT) then do it as (CPTE_CLIENT)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `PIVOT`

Find the `total` per `JOUR` using `SUM over()` in pivot source query.

```
SELECT jour,
       CA_TTC=total,
       [CREDIT CARD]=Isnull([CREDIT CARD], 0),
       [CHECK]=Isnull([CHECK], 0),
       [SPECIES]=Isnull([SPECIES], 0)
FROM   (SELECT *,
               Sum(CA_TTC)OVER(partition BY JOUR) total
        FROM   Your_result) a
       PIVOT (Max(CA_TTC)
             FOR LIBELLE IN([CREDIT CARD],
                            [CHECK],
                            [SPECIES])) pv
```

- [**SQLFIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cb76c/1)

Comment: PIVOT seems to be the good way, i will try it
I'm searching for the best modular way, it will be great if users can choose which 'LIBELLE' they want to display
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Another method is to use conditional aggregation or `SUM(CASE WHEN ... END)`:

```
;WITH CTE([JOUR], [CA TTC], [LIBELLE]) AS(
    SELECT 
        TE.DATE AS 'JOUR', 
        SUM(TE.TOTAL_TTC) AS 'CA TTC', 
        ME.LIBELLE AS 'LIBELLE'
    FROM TICKET TE
    INNER JOIN MODE_REGLEMENT ME ON ME.CODE = TE.MODE_REGLEMENT
    GROUP BY TE.DATE, ME.LIBELLE
)
SELECT
    [JOUR],
    [CA TTC] =
        SUM(CASE WHEN [LIBELLE] = 'CREDIT CARD' THEN [CA TTC] ELSE 0 END) +
        SUM(CASE WHEN [LIBELLE] = 'CHECK' THEN [CA TTC] ELSE 0 END) +
        SUM(CASE WHEN [LIBELLE] = 'SPECIES' THEN [CA TTC] ELSE 0 END),
    [CREDIT CARD] = SUM(CASE WHEN [LIBELLE] = 'CREDIT CARD' THEN [CA TTC] ELSE 0 END),
    [CHECK] = SUM(CASE WHEN [LIBELLE] = 'CHECK' THEN [CA TTC] ELSE 0 END),
    [SPECIES] = SUM(CASE WHEN [LIBELLE] = 'SPECIES' THEN [CA TTC] ELSE 0 END)               
FROM CTE
GROUP BY [JOUR]
```

Comment: yeah i know `case when` i use it in others requests :) 
your method seems to be great but i find it a bit redundant